# Não consigo gravar dados em um arquivo txt

Tags: delphi

Código:

```
qr.ParamByName('mes').AsString:= edmes.Text;
qr.ParamByName('ano').AsString:= edano.Text;
qr.Active:= true;
qr.First;
try
  AssignFile(arq, 'relatorio.txt');
  Rewrite(arq);

  showmessage(inttostr(qr.RecordCount));

  while not qr.Eof do
  begin
    writeln(arq, qr.FieldValues['dt_ficha'] + ';' + qr.FieldValues['unidade'] + ';' + qr.FieldValues['profissional'] + ';' + qr.FieldValues['count']);
    qr.Next;
  end;

  CloseFile(arq);
  ShowMessage('Arquivo criado com sucesso!');
except
end;
```

O componente qr é executado corretamente, o showmessage me informa que tem 270 linhas, mas o comando while só é executado uma vez (uma linha apenas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente desta forma

```
qr.ParamByName('mes').AsString:= edmes.Text;
qr.ParamByName('ano').AsString:= edano.Text;
qr.Open;

try
  AssignFile(arq, 'relatorio.txt');
  Rewrite(arq);

  showmessage(inttostr(qr.RecordCount));
  qr.First;
  while(not(qr.Eof))do
  begin
    writeln(arq, DateTimeToStr(qr.FieldValues['dt_ficha']) + ';' + qr.FieldValues['unidade'] + ';' + qr.FieldValues['profissional'] + ';' + IntToStr(qr.FieldValues['count']));
    qr.Next;
  end;

  CloseFile(arq);
  ShowMessage('Arquivo criado com sucesso!');
except
  On E: Exception do
    ShowMessage(E.message);
end;
```

Comment: nao funcionou. pior que esse procedimento é simples e nao estou entendendo qual o erro...

Comment: Qual sua versão do delphi? Você programou alguma coisa em algum dos eventos da query? Antes do `writeln` coloque isso `ShowMessage(IntToStr(qr.recno))` e veja se na primeira vez que entra se está no RecNo 0 ou 1

Comment: usando recno aparece 1

Comment: minha versao é o rad studio 10.2

Comment: estou usando zeos para conectar, os dados sao listados no grid na tela normalmente, só na hora de percorrer o arquivo que ele nao faz

Comment: Confira minha resposta novamente, altera o `exception` da forma que mostrei, é para ser exibido o erro, acredito que está dando erro ao salvar seu arquivo de texto, por isso passa uma vez só. E mais uma coisa... Se você está na versão 10.2 que é a mais atual, use os componentes `FireDAC` ao invés de Zeos, são muito melhores

Comment: isso mesmo amigo, obrigado. está pedindo pra converter uma variavel do tipo date (dt_ficha) para string

Comment: estou usando zeos que é gratis (minha versao do delphi é uma gratuita, pois nao quis pegar versao pirata), é possivel instalar o FireDAC nela? pode alterar sua resposta pra eu dar teus pontos

Comment: Resposta editada. Seguindo a lógica, possivelmente seu campo `count` daria problema também por ser inteiro (acredito eu). E no caso do delphi gratuito, então beleza, fireDAC é mais para a versão paga mesmo.

Comment: isso mesmo, alterei o campo `count` também e já estou usando o sistema. abraço ^^